# Trying to bind result of a Linq Query into a graph

Tags: c#, linq, charts

I'm trying to draw a graph with a list of year (x axis) and the count of items (y axis).
I have too many years so i'd like to regroup into an "other" category for the years > 1985 and < 1975.
The linq query (i think) works but it's the bind to the Grapht that doesnt work, i have a system.ArgumentException at run time :

"Les points de données de séries ne prennent pas en charge les valeurs de type <>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.String,System.Int32]" 
sorry it's in french (how to get these exceptions in english ??) but is says that the chart doesnt accept anonymous type [string, int] (which is the result of my query).

Here is the query :

```
            var result = from orig_year in Globals.ds.Tables["Song"].AsEnumerable()
                     let newListofYear = getYear(orig_year.Field<int>("year"))
                     orderby orig_year.Field<int>("year")
                     group orig_year by newListofYear into new_year
                     select new
                     {
                         year = new_year.Key,
                         counte = new_year.Count(),
                     };
```

The function GetYear :

```
protected static string getYear(int year)
    {
        if (year < 1975 || year > 1985)
            return "other";
        else
            return Convert.ToString(year);
    }
```

and the bind to the Chart :

```
chart2.DataSource = result.ToArray();
chart2.DataBind();
```

The exception is thrown at the Databind statement.
I've tried the .ToArray to no success.
Thanks in advance

EDIT : 
Thanks to Gert, i had to set the following properties :

```
chart2.Series[0].XValueMember = "year";
chart2.Series[0].YValueMembers = "counte";
```

Comment: Well, first obvious thing to try is offer a named type. Note that we don't know your chart component.

Comment: you nailed it Gert, i'm posting the update. thanks